# Building a tree with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to web scraping.

What I basically want to do is to scrape the following website: https://www.admin.ch/opc/fr/classified-compilation/national.html, which is referencing all the Swiss federal law.
The structure of the website is tree-like (you start with categories: Etat – Peuple – Autorités, Défense nationale, and so on; which contain sub-categories, until you reach the leaves- the legal texts) and I would like to get the same structure in a JSON file.

Here is the spider I have written for the moment:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import XMLFeedSpider

from admin_ch.helpers.helper_functions import is_article_number, is_int, is_final_article

class Spider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = "spider_droit_interne"
    allowed_domains = ["admin.ch"]
    start_urls = [
            'https://www.admin.ch/opc/fr/classified-compilation/national.html'
            ]
    itertag = 'item'  

    def parse(self, response):
        for category in response.xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr'):
            cat_number = category.xpath('td/text()').extract_first()
            cat_name = cat_number + ' ' + category.xpath('td/a/text()').extract_first()
            url = category.xpath('td/a/@href').extract_first()
            url = response.urljoin(url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_category, meta={'name': cat_name})
            return #Just do the 1st category as an example

    def parse_category(self, response):
        name = response.meta['name']
        tree = {}
        node = {}
        for category in response.xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr'):
            cat_number = category.xpath('td/text()').extract_first()
            cat_name = cat_number + ' ' + category.xpath('td/a/text()').extract_first()
            if is_int(cat_number) and len(cat_number) < 3:
                url = category.xpath('td/a/@href').extract_first()
                url = response.urljoin(url)
                if is_final_article(url):
                    node[cat_name] = 'leaf reached!!!!!'
                    yield node
                else:
                    #node[cat_name] = 'more nodes'
                    yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.get_article, meta={'name': cat_name})
        tree[name] = node
        yield tree

    def get_article(self, response):
        name = response.meta['name']
        tree = {}
        node = {}
        for category in response.xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr'):
            cat_number = category.xpath('td/text()').extract()[1]
            for element in [' ', '\n', '\r']:
                cat_number = cat_number.replace(element, '')
            if is_article_number(cat_number):
                url = category.xpath('td/a/@href').extract_first()
                url = response.urljoin(url)
                if is_final_article(url):
                    node[cat_number] = 'leaf reached!!!!!'
                else:
                    node[cat_number] = cat_number
                    #yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.get_article, meta={'tree': item})
                    #The content is not important for the moment, only the structure
        tree[name] = node
        yield tree
```

The helper functions are only checking regular expressions, nothing really important in our case (because they do work):

```
import re

def is_article_number(string):
    regex_article_number = '^[0-9]+[.[0-9]+]*$'
    return re.match(regex_article_number, string)

def is_int(string):
    regex_integer = '^[0-9]+'
    return re.match(regex_integer, string)

def is_final_article(url):
    return url.endswith('index.html')
```

The result I get from this is terribly wrong, could you help me out with this please?

Comment: What is the result you are getting vs what is expected?

Comment: I dont see you are building a tree as the craw process runs. In the "recursive" methods, you plant a tree, by `tree={}` and there is no time in which your tree grows like `tree=tree+ ...` try sending the tree built in each level as a part of the meta: `meta={'name': cat_name, 'tree':tree}`

Comment: @sniperd I've got a flat structure like you can see here: [link](https://ibb.co/mvsOGc)
I'd like the nodes 1 to ten to go inside "1 Etat – Peuple – Autorités".
That's because I yield instead of assigning node[cat_name] in parse_category.

Comment: @Evhz I did what you suggested and I almost got the right result. I now have a russian doll thing, as you can see [here](https://ibb.co/epwQwc)

Comment: @MatthiasRamirez Good! work a bit the recursion and it's there.